# how to prevent a field in POJO class from not inserted as duplicate values in java

Tags: java, mongodb

i am passing a POJO class as my request body in POST Method, now i should not save a field of that POJO class which is already exists in MongoDB collection data. in short i should not save the existing field into database if tried to do that it should through error item already exists.
FYI:- my POJO class is

```
public class Items {
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    
    private String itemName;
    
}
```

now the item should not be duplicate.
public void addCategory(Items item) {

```
    String itemName = item.getItemName();
    
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(itemName);
    for (String itemList : items) {
        if (!items.contains(itemList)) {
            items.add(items);
             mongoTemplate.save(items);
        }
        
    }
```

**this is not working well. it is taking same values again .**
*can any one help me with this.*

Comment: `items.add(itemName);` after this line, items will have single string in it and you are iterating same list and checking if list has its element , you need to rename variables relook into  what are existing list you need to check against the new value

Comment: @sanjeevRm either can you give reference link for this::-->>
i am passing a POJO class as my request body in POST Method, now i should not save a field of that POJO class which is already exists in MongoDB collection data. in short i should not save the existing field into database if tried to do that it should through error item already exists. FYI:- my POJO class is

Comment: before saving record, you should check if it exists in db, search record by its unique key?

Comment: i have to check whether the itemName is already exists in DB or not. if exits it should not add. likewise everytime if i am trying to save the already existing itemName it should take. this is my question. can you share me sample code how can i restrict this @sanjeevRm